# HTTPS self signed certificate

Tags: android, https, connection

I have a server with https with self signed certificate and client application on Android. On client i just disable certificate verification with 
`urlConnection.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());` 
In this case connection will be secure or this is just disable https and makes connection over http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the URL you open starts with `https://`, the connection will be secure. However, you will be vulnerable to [Man-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), since someone could just use any self-signed certificate to impersonate your server.

Comment: The connection will be encrypted, but SSL won't be able to verify who you're talking to, so it won't be as secure.